# How to describe a person who puts down others to make themself feel superior

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to describe a character who insults and degrades everyone around her to feel better and to give the appearance that she is superior to everyone else. This character doesn't actually dislike anyone, but feels compelled to act in an arrogant manner because of her high social standing. Is there any word or phrase that can help me describe this person, particularly something that implies the motivation behind her disrespectful actions?

Comment: Explaining the motivation behind her actions is like guessing why she behaves in such an ***arrogant*** way and this make this question an opinion-based one.

Comment: @Josh61 By motivation I simply mean her desire to feel superior to others.

Comment: so it's a rich person, who degrades those beneath her.  so you're saying the person is rude - BUT - **only because** she (mistakenly, as it were) feels that rich people are supposed to be rude.  is that right ?!?!

Comment: @JoeBlow That is correct.

Comment: as Josh says, "arrogant" is probably the word you're after.  If you are trying to explain some amazingly subtle variation on that ... I mean ... I can't even think of an adjective for something as subtle as *My Funny Valentine* .. I don't know

Comment: I have a further question.  In fact IS SHE "GOOD AT HEART" and MISGUIDED in this affected snobbery?  Or in fact is she ACTUALLY CRUELLA D'VILLE, but, uh, just sort of incidentally does this affected snobbery?

Comment: @JoeBlow I was hoping for something slightly better than arrogance but I can understand if no such word exists. She certainly falls into the good at heart and misguided category.

Comment: You sound like she has been *corrupted* or *deviated* from her fundamentally  good personality,  sort of *victim* of the system herself.

Comment: right.  perhaps you just say "a kind of misguided arrogance"

Comment: Not clear why no one suggests [_condescending_](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/condescending)? Motivation is speculative as someone else hinted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A narcissist.  Somebody can have narcissistic tendencies or characteristics or, at the extreme, Narcissistic Personality Disorder.

However, I don't think this fits with the idea of social standing or social superiority.  That is more akin to snobbery.

There is also "social elitist" or "social elitism" which may imply the kind of behaviour you describe.

"Nouveau riche" (new money) describes people who lack social grace and manners and therefore may behave in the way you describe, but this term also implies other behaviour such as vulgar consumerism, and material wealth rather than any cunning or devious tendency to put people down.

narcissistic tendencies induced by social elitism...?

Comment: Hi @Rosamunda and welcome to ELU. Thank you for posting a considered answer to the above question. You may wish to support your answer by adding links to definitions for 'narcissist', 'social elitism' and 'nouveau riche'. Reputable sources include [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com) and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com)

Answer (score 1):

**Imperious**, perhaps?  "Expecting people to obey you and treating them as if they are not as important as you" ([citation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/imperious)).

Answer (score 0):

**Overbearing**

> unpleasantly overpowering.

**Self-important**

> having an exaggerated sense of one's own value or importance.

**Egotistical**

> excessively conceited or absorbed in oneself; self-centred.

**Egocentric**

> thinking only of oneself, without regard for the feelings or desires of others; self-centred.

Egomania is also known as an **obsessive preoccupation with one's self** and applies to someone who follows their own ungoverned impulses and is possessed by delusions of personal greatness and feels a lack of appreciation. Someone suffering from this extreme egocentric focus is an egomaniac.(Source: Wikipedia)

Remember, egotistical < egocentric < egomaniac.

Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/

Answer (score 0):

The only reason people behave like this, surely, is because of a deep-seated sense of ***inferiority***. But we have strayed into the realm of psychoanalysis.

Answer (score -1):

So you're saying

> "A rich person, who degrades those beneath her. BUT - only because she (mistakenly, as it were) feels that rich people are supposed to be rude."

My God, that's so subtle.

Could it possibly be that what you're getting at is she's a "**try-hard**" or similar?  As a Scottish grandmother might say, she's a "would-be that could-be" (i.e,, a faker, someone not from the manner born who wants to be)?

Do you possibly mean a

## nouveau-riche

type??  that is sometimes used to imply **fake, didn't grow-up-with-it imperiousness**.  (Although more usually, just "very poor taste in handbags, buys expensive cars foolishly thinking that's what rich people do," etc.)

Comment: Uhm..doesn't nouveau-riche mean 'the new rich'? I mean that's the class of people that has recently acquired wealth and doesn't know how to use it. In a desperate attempt to climb up the social ladder, these people buy all those things that they feel, will make them look richer.